# How do I install the hadoop-examples* and hadoop-test* jars in HDP 2.2?

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

How do I install the hadoop-examples* and hadoop-test* jars on Hortonworks Data Platform 2.2?  The jars do not exist on any of the servers.  Is there another package that I need to install?

I found a [reference](http://hortonworks.com/kb/test-mapreduce-setup/) that says they should be located at `/usr/share/hadoop`, but that directory does not exist on any of the nodes in my cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most things moved under /usr/hdp for HDP 2.2 so these are probably what you are looking for.

```
[hdpdemo@hdp-demo-mas5 hdp]$ pwd
/usr/hdp
[hdpdemo@hdp-demo-mas5 hdp]$ ls 
2.2.0.0-2041  current
[hdpdemo@hdp-demo-mas5 hdp]$ find ./2.2.0.0-2041 -name "hadoop*examples*"
./2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar
./2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar
./2.2.0.0-2041/knox/samples/hadoop-examples.jar
[hdpdemo@hdp-demo-mas5 hdp]$ find ./2.2.0.0-2041 -name "hadoop*test*"
./2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/hadoop-common-tests.jar
./2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041-tests.jar
./2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041-tests.jar
./2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-tests.jar
./2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests.jar
./2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar
./2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-tests.jar
./2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041-tests.jar
[hdpdemo@hdp-demo-mas5 hdp]$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install hadoop packages, Hadoop libraries can be installed in two ways using RPM or you can use Tarball

> RPM (Binary - Requires sudo access)

Step 1 : Configuring [Remote repository](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.2.4/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-3.html) 
Step 2 : Install hadoop libraries - [Refer this link](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.2.4/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap2-2.html)

> Tarball  (Source + Binary : No need of sudo access just need to
>   extract )

Get tar ball from the [link](http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/1.x/updates/1.2.1/tars/hadoop-1.1.2.23.tar.gz) extract and use it.

Once the installation is done using RPM, you can use either locate command or find command for locating these jars. In case of Tarball you can location hadoop libraries within the extracted directory.

```
locate hadoop-test.jar hadoop-examples.jar

find /usr -iname hadoop-test.jar
```

Comment: The jars do not exist on the servers.  I am curious if there is a package that I need to install.  I should be more clear in my question.  Thanks.

Comment: Which rpm package contains the correct jar files?  Thanks for the information, but I know how to install packages.  I just need to know which one.

Comment: If you just need the jar files you don't have to install any packages, you may download from the hadoop maven repositiry .. 
http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-examples/
http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-test/